# Can I use The Sonos API to play Dolby Atmos music?

Tags: sonos

I'm developing a proof of concept for a client that is interested in using Sonos devices to build surround sound audio experiences for customers. They want to stream a unique audio stream to their customers based on the local atmosphere and other variables measured on location.

I have the following question: I have already built a simple prototype to load a URL into the Sonos App. I'm currently testing using an older Sonos One SL Model. But before I buy an entire Sonos setup for testing I would like to know if It's even possible to use the Sonos API to load these audio formats.

- Is it possible to load Dolby (Atmos) Digital (Plus), Dolby Atmos, and Dolby (Atmos) TrueHD files using the Sonos API? It is listed under supported home theater formats but not under the supported audio formats for the Sonos music library. Should I pass it as an MP4 Container format?
- Under supported home theater formats it says that I should have at least a Sonos Arc, Arc SL, or Beam (gen 2). For Dolby TrueHD, it also says I require an additional "eARC" connection. I assume that means for HDMI? If I need this eARC connection for Dolby TrueHD, then I can't use the API right? So I would need a local machine for every client, connected to their local network that can stream through an "eARC" connection? Or does all of this only apply when connected to a TV? I'm a developer first and not an audio expert, so excuse me if my knowledge about some things is very limited.
- Another issue is bandwidth, my client wants to use the Sonos Era 300, assuming that I don't need a home theater product to stream Dolby TrueHD (or other Dobly formats), can they handle the enormous bandwidth required over Wifi or do they have to be connected via a LAN cable to the network?

I tried played a TrueHD file, demuxed from a blueray with Dolby support but I only got weird audio artifacts (a short beep every 4 seconds)

Comment: I doubt the streaming API works with Atmos content, but have no way to verify. What "enormous bandwidth" are you talking about? Compared to video, audio is always tiny.

The known way to stream Atmos to Sonos devices is to create a music service integration (on your local network) which is how Amazon do it.